Fundamental group of spherical $3$-manifold
I'm learning some concepts of geometric group theory and I'm a quite confusing about that: I want to undertand the fundamental group of a $3$-manifold $M$ of the form $M = S^3/\Gamma$ (a manifold with spherecial geometry). The wikipedia says the following: The fundamental group is either cyclic, or is a central extension of a dihedral, tetrahedral, octahedral, or icosahedral group by a cyclic group of even order. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold#Properties)
But the book of Thurston say the following:

It seems that the results say different things.

Why do you think they're different?

@SteveD I think they are different, but I cannot see why they are the same. I know that central extensions of $C_2$ are not necessarily direct or semidirect product so both statement can match. But I would like to see an explanation why they say the same thing

The Wikipedia article actually goes into detail about which central extensions it's talking about. Perhaps that will help identifying the two lists? The icosahedral/octahedral cases are the easiest to see.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Here's the correspondence between the two lists.

The dihedral case of the Wikipedia article gives fundamental group
\begin{equation}
G \cong\langle x,y\mid y^x=y^{-1}, x^{2n}=y^m\rangle
\end{equation}
where $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Let $K=\langle x^2\rangle$ and $L=\langle y\rangle$. Both are normal in $G$, and
\begin{align}
G/K &\cong D_{2m}\\
G/L &\cong C_{2n}
\end{align}
Meanwhile $Z:=K\cap L=\langle x^{2n}\rangle$, a central subgroup of order $2$. If $n$ is odd, then $G/Z\cong D_{2m}\times C_n$, which is case (b) of Thurston. Otherwise, when $n$ is even (so $m$ is odd), there is a map
\begin{equation}
 G/Z\rightarrow G/K\times G/L
\end{equation}
and order considerations show the image $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $D_{2m}\times C_{2n}$, which is case (d) of Thurston. Conversely, the subgroups of index $2$ as in case (d) are given by:


$D_{2m}\times C_n$; this case doesn't happen.
$C_m\times C_{2n}\cong C_{2mn}$, which is case (a).
The subgroup $H$ from above.


The tetrehedral case from Wikipedia gives the fundamental group
\begin{equation}
G\cong \langle x,y,z\mid x^2=y^2=(xy)^2, x^z=y, y^z=xy, z^{3m}=1\rangle
\end{equation}
where $m$ is odd. Let $K=\langle x^2,z^3\rangle$ and $L=\langle x,y\rangle$. Both are normal in $G$, and
\begin{align}
G/K &\cong A_4\\
G/L &\cong C_{3m}
\end{align}
Meanwhile $Z:=K\cap L=\langle x^2\rangle$, a central subgroup of order $2$. If $m$ is coprime to $3$, then $G/Z\cong A_4\times C_m$, which is case (b) of Thurston. Otherwise, $3$ divides $m$ and just as above, there's a map
\begin{equation}
G/Z\rightarrow G/K\times G/L
\end{equation}
and order considerations show the image $H$ is a subgroup of index $3$ in $A_4\times C_{3m}$, which is case (c) of Thurston. Conversely, the subgroups of index $3$ in $A_4\times C_{3m}$ are given by:


$A_4\times C_m$; this case doesn't happen.
$C_2\times C_2\times C_{3m}$; this is case (b) (since $C_2\times C_2$ is a dihedral group).
The subgroup $H$ from above.
Another subgroup $H'$, which is isomorphic to $H$.


The octahedral case from Wikipedia is just $2O\times C_m$ with $m$ coprime to $|O|$, and quotienting out by the center in $2O$ gives $O\times C_m$, which is case (b) of Thurston.
The icosahedral case from Wikipedia is just $2I\times C_m$ with $m$ coprime to $|I|$, and quotienting out be the center in $2I$ gives $I\times C_m$, which is case (b) of Thurston.


Awesome! This is (really) a great answer!
